# Como almaceno el numero de registros que se almaceno en un cursor

Tags: count

espero esten muy bien y me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente:

He creado un cursos donde almaceno el resultado de un select con varias variables, despues de eso, necesito contar el numero de registros que genera ese select, almacenar en una variable ese total de registros para despues imprimirlo con dbms_output.put_line

Si me hago entender, feliz noche

Comment: Hola! Cuál cursor, cuál select, cuál variable? Qué error te sale? Por favor ve a [edit] e incluye la información relevante

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola dandres31, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son, si nos indicas el lenguaje de la aplicación, mucho mejor.